# Using Javascript to Filter a HTML ul li if string contains word

Tags: javascript, html

I have this bit of javascript code which filters the list items returning items containing the first word put into the search box:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.onkeyup = function () {
var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerHTML;
    if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) 
        lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
    else
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

This script only works for the first word typed, not the second.

For example if I had a search query named "car", it should return:

- blue car
- red car
- black car

At the moment the query returns nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer for accurate words. and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0)
```

to

```
if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)
```

and it works for the entire string, not just the first word.

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is

```
if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0)
```

use

```
if (name.toUpperCase().split(' ').indexOf(filter) >= 0)
```

It will search accurate words in the name.